# DrawLine doesn't work in android2.2, why?

Tags: android, draw, paint, android-canvas

When the following code is executing on emulator with `android 2.3` it worked, but when running it on `android 2.2` nothing appear ... why ?

```
public class BubbleView extends View {

    Paint paint,paint2;

    int pos, x2,y2;

    public BubbleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setTextSize(25);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);



        paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint2.setTextSize(25);
        paint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        int x = getMeasuredWidth()/2;
        int y = getMeasuredHeight()/2;
        float r = Math.max(x, y)*0.6f;
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 12 , paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r , paint);
        canvas.drawLine(x-r, y, x+r, y, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(x, y-r, x, y+r, paint);

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you found the solution of your problem ? I am having the same issue with Android 4.4 in which the `drawLine` method is not working to draw the lines.